# How to call one test cases from one file another

Tags: robotframework

I have written a few test cases but some of them can be reused instead of writing them again in the new scripts. So if I have an Input text keyword for one field declared on one page how can that be used in an another test cases w/o having to mention the same keyword and locator again.

Comment: Welcome to [so] were we try to help with your programming difficulties. In order to do so it is common to provide a [mcve] to show what you are working and a description of the actual and desired outcome. Anything else that you've tried is also helpful to know. To understand what makes a good question read through the [ask] of the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user defined Keyword in robot framework and paste your test case scripts inside the keyword then use keyword to execute your tests

Follow this documentation to create a user defined keywords,

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-user-keywords

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at this [Link](https://github.com/robotframework/HowToWriteGoodTestCases/blob/master/HowToWriteGoodTestCases.rst)

Robot Framework allows the use of Keywords, I would suggest to create a diffrent folder with all the keywords e.g To open the browser or login with a user to website or what ever you want.

You can create your logic inside the keyword section, and then pass the Name of the Custom Created keyword (Equal String) to the Test script.

Example of Keywords.

keywords.robot

```
*** Keywords ***
Equal String
   Should be equal  Hello   Hello
```

Tests.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        keywords.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Validate Equal String
   Equal String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only share keywords, not tests.
https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2591